# Why does this GridBagLayout not appear as planned?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I was trying to achieve the end result required in [Setting an arbitrary width in GridBagLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27348688/418556).

For easy reference, here it is:

[image]

This is the current result:

[image]

Button number and row is shown in the form `1,1`, followed by the number of columns `(2)` declared for this cell.

As you can see, it starts with buttons `1,1 (3)` and below it `1,2 (4)` being the same width, while declaring different numbers of columns.

Can anyone determine how to correct the code?

The current code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class KeyBoardLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    KeyBoardLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,1 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 7;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 9;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 13;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 15;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,1 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 18;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,1 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,2 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 8;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 10;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 12;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 14;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 16;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 18;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,2 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,3 (5)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 7;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 9;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 13;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 15;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 17;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 19;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,3 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,4 (10)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 16;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 19;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,4 (3)"), gbc);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                KeyBoardLayout o = new KeyBoardLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Keyboard Layout");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I spent a really, really long time trying to get something like this to work and eventually gave up and wrote my own layout manager :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I've tried writing a custom layout manager ..once.  A `ScrollLayout`.  I ran it by one of the gurus of layouts and he commented WTE that it 'could use some improvement'.  Since he was a really, *really* nice guy who did not like offending people - I took that to mean that my efforts were closer to 'pathetic, with a  fragile result'.  ;)

Comment: Yeah, it was purpose built JUST for that task

Comment: From what I can "guess", `GridBagLayout` doesn't like half filling a column where the contents of the column expands beyond that columns scope - It may have something to do with the `fill` attribute

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622279/laying-out-a-keyboard-in-swing/24625704#24625704) - Doesn't use `GridBagLayout`, but it's an idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the picture each row contains 5 to 9 buttons, which means the `GridBagLayout` only knows about the width of 9 individual columns.

Add up the numbers in the (..) which indicate the total `gridwidth` for each row. The total is 22.

The `GridBagLayout` doesn't know how to turn 9 columns into 22 columns. It doesn't know what widths to use for columns without a component in the column. So the layout doesn't know how to handle the `gridwidth` constraint.

The solution is to tell the `GridBagLayout` the intended number of columns in the grid and the minimum width of each column in the grid.

This can be done by setting values of the `GridBagLayout` itself:

```
//ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
int[] columns = new int[22];
Arrays.fill(columns, 30);
GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
gbl.columnWidths = columns;
ui = new JPanel(gbl);
```

The size of the array defines the number of columns.

The value assigned to each entry in the array is the "minimum width" of the column (it can be different for each column).

Now the `GridBagLayout` knows how to calculate a width for each column and using `gridwidth` as a constraint for each component will work as expected.

Updated code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class KeyBoardLayout {

    private JComponent ui = null;

    KeyBoardLayout() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui!=null) return;


        //ui = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        int[] columns = new int[22];
        Arrays.fill(columns, 30);
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl.columnWidths = columns;
        ui = new JPanel(gbl);

        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,1 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 7;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 9;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 13;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,1 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 15;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,1 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 18;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,1 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,2 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 4;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 8;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 10;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 12;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 14;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 16;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,2 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 18;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,2 (4)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,3 (5)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 5;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 7;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 9;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 11;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 13;
        ui.add(new JButton("6,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 15;
        ui.add(new JButton("7,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 17;
        ui.add(new JButton("8,3 (2)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 19;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("9,3 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("1,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("2,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 6;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        ui.add(new JButton("3,4 (10)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 16;
        gbc.gridwidth = 3;
        ui.add(new JButton("4,4 (3)"), gbc);

        gbc.gridx = 19;
        ui.add(new JButton("5,4 (3)"), gbc);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                KeyBoardLayout o = new KeyBoardLayout();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Keyboard Layout");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Which would give the following layout:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiqAz.png]

This approach can be used for rows as well.

This means the `GridBagLayout` provides the ability to create a grid and only fill a few cells of the grid with components.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid the desired layout is not so simple with simple GridBagLayout restriction. GBL does not respect proportions with gridwidth. It means it can't detect 2/3 of component's width.
So if you define

```
c1 (gridwidth=2) c2 (gridwidth=1)
c3 (gridwidth=3)
```

Expecting to get

```
|****|**|
|*******|
```

The result will be

```
|**|**|
|*****|
```

The camickr's example works because the simple cell heights were defined and IMHO that's the only way.