# Setting GridBagLayout grid's size

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create a console using Java Swing (GridBagLayout).

I don't know why, but as you can see at the left margin, grids don't have the correct size.

[image: The code output]

It's supposed to be shown this way:
[image]

Where light blue is the list, green the image, orange the text panel and yellow the text field.

I don't know how to make the list bigger and the image smaller. Too, the text field's grid is binded to the list one, even tough the list is on y 1 and the text field on y 2.

Here's some code.

```
// Command List
DefaultListModel<String> listInput = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listInput);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
list.setBackground(new Color(160, 160, 160));
list.setSelectionBackground(new Color(150, 150, 150));
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 20));
manager.setCommandList(listInput);

    c.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
    c.ipady = 0;
    c.ipadx = 100;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 1;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 2;
    c.weightx = 0.1;
    c.weighty = 0.6;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
console.add(scrollPane, c);

// Image Displayer
JLabel image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());
manager.setImageField(image);

    c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
    c.ipady = 0;
    c.ipadx = 0;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridheight = 1;
    c.weightx = 0.1;
    c.weighty = 0.3;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
console.add(image, c);
```

where 'c' is a grid bag constraint and console the main JPanel.
As you can see, the list has a grid height of 2 and weight of 0.6, and the image a grid height of 1 and weight of 0.9, so not sure why the list is 4 times smaller than the image.

Another issue, I've added a listener to the JLabel holding the image (on resize), anyways, it isn't called. Should I add the listener to the main panel? as the image is only being resized by the layout manager.

Thanks ^^

EDIT:
SSCCE:

```
package co.relieved.jelly.application.display.swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JPanel {

    static JLabel image;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        display();
        try {
            BufferedImage buffer = ImageIO
                .read(new File("/home/juanco/Pictures/Screenshot from 2016-02-08 22-43-22.png"));
            image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                buffer.getScaledInstance(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Test() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 1));
        JTabbedPane tabs = new JTabbedPane();

        /*** >>> Console Pane <<< ***/
        JPanel console = new JPanel();
        console.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;

        // Console Screen
        JTextPane screen = new JTextPane();
        screen.setEditable(false);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.weightx = 0.8;
        c.weighty = 1;
        console.add(screen, c);

        // Console Input
        JTextField input = new JTextField();

        c.insets = new Insets(2, 0, 2, 0);
        c.ipady = 3;
        c.gridy = 2;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weighty = 0;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        console.add(input, c);

        // Command List
        DefaultListModel<String> listInput = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        listInput.setSize(1);
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listInput);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);

        c.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
        c.ipady = 0;
        c.ipadx = 100;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridheight = 2;
        c.weightx = 0.1;
        c.weighty = 0.6;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        console.add(scrollPane, c);

        // Image Displayer
        image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon());

        c.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridheight = 1;
        c.weighty = 0.3;
        console.add(image, c);

        // General
        tabs.addTab("Console", console);

        /*** >>> Logs Pane <<< ***/
        JPanel logs = new JPanel();

        tabs.addTab("Logs", logs);

        // Setup
        tabs.setSelectedIndex(0);
        add(tabs);
    }

    static void display() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Relieved Console");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500));
        frame.add(new Test(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Full Code:` - no it isn't the full code. The posted code does not compile. Anyway, we don't want the full code of your application. We want a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. That is create a simple class with a frame and 4 components. Try to add the 4 components in the layout you want. The tabbed pane and all the other code is irrelevant to the problem of just try to lay out components on the frame. Once you get the SSCCE working then you fix your real code.

Comment: Like that? I removed all unnecessary code, it will print the same output without colors/format

Comment: `I removed all unnecessary code` - not really. Your question is about the height of the components. All the code related to the padding or insets has nothing to do with getting the height to occupy two grids. Also, the image is irrelevant. All you need is a label with text to simulate the component in the cell. Also, I would suggest you logically reorder your code to make it more readable. People design grids from left to right and top to bottom. So you should create the component for cell y = 0, x = 0/1 and then y = 1, x = 0/1 so that you build the grid one row at a time.

Comment: The code is ordered by functionality, not by how it's displayed, as it's a fragment of a big api and I need to find everything fast by functionality. If I change any of those padding, the grid will be displayed different (that grid would be smaller). There are only 3 insets, I suppose you can live with that. Also, I've already figured out a fix for this, thanks a lot, it's explained on my answer to this Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Here's some code.

Which doesn't help. The grid can only be completed with the entire code. That is we need to know the gridwidth and gridheight for all components in order to determine the allocation of space to each component in the grid.

> the text field's grid is binded to the list one, even tough the list is on y 1 and the text field on y 2.

You can't just randomly assign a component to a grid. The component will only go to grid 2 if the component above it has a grid height of 2. So basically each of your columns needs to have components with a total grid height of 3.

> I don't know how to make the list bigger

Setting a preferred size of (20, 20) doesn't help. Anyway you should not be using the setPreferredSize() method.

Instead you should be using:

```
list.setVisibleRowCount(...);
```

to specify the visible rows. Then the JList can determine its own preferred size.

Another layout option is to use nested panels which can simplify the layout.

So you could start with a "west" panel that uses a BorderLayout. Then you add the label to "PAGE_START" and the list to "CENTER".

Then you create a "center" panel. Add the main component to the "CENTER" and the text field to the "PAGE_START".

Then you add the two panels to the frame:

```
frame.add(westPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Edit:

Sorry, I take back my comment about making each column have a grid height of 3. You can't just specify a total grid height of 3 because you only have 2 components in each column, so each component can only have a height of 1.

Check out my answer in this posting: [Why does this GridBagLayout not appear as planned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27371956/why-does-this-gridbaglayout-not-appear-as-planned/27372407#27372407) for a hack that allows you to manipulate gridHeight/Weight by using invisible components in a row/column.

However, I don't recommend that approach. it will be far easier to use my suggestion of nested panels using a BorderLayout (or some other layout manager on the nested panels).

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response.

The set prefered size method is just to add a value to the jlabel, if the jlabel is empty, the grid will expand even more

Going to add the full code. Anyways, every colum has a total grid height of 3

Comment: @Juanco - You are setting the preferred size of the scroll pane. Don't do that. I told you the proper way to suggest a size for the JList.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you would need to also specify the `gridwidth` and/or `gridheight` for the text field as well.

GridBagLayout is like a glorified GridLayout. It will attempt to align all of the components with the nearest grid spaces around it. [Oracle's Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) also describe this behavior.

Much of the time, issues with laying out components using GridBagLayout come from the other components being added to the layout instead of the apparent problem child.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it splitting the "console" JPanel in two, a border layout panel to the left and a grid bag layout panel to the right. As @camickr suggested