# Java Swing keyboard not formatting properly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, layout-manager

I'm currently making a GUI for a small game project, but I'm having trouble with the keyboard layout, specifically with the home row and bottom row. I missed it entirely looking through my code, but I have this piece of code:

```
        home = new JButton[homeRow.length];
        JPanel homekeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, homeRow.length));
        for(int i = 0; i < homeRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton homesize = new JButton(homeRow[i]);
            homesize.setSize(50, 50);
            home[i] = homesize;
            keyboard.add(home[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(homekeys);

        bottom = new JButton[bottomRow.length];
        JPanel bottomkeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, bottomRow.length));
        for(int i = 0; i < bottomRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton bottomsize = new JButton(bottomRow[i]);
            bottomsize.setSize(50, 50);
            bottom[i] = bottomsize;
            keyboard.add(bottom[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(topkeys);
```

where `keyboard.add(topkeys)` should have really been `keyboard.add(bottomkeys)`, though it's exactly in the format I want:

[image: keyboard.add(topkeys)]

But when I change it to `keyboard.add(bottomkeys)`, there is a weird format:
[image: keyboard.add(bottomkeys)]

Why is it being formatted strangely when I change it to use `bottomkeys`, and how would I fix this?

Here is the entire code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class GameGUI extends JFrame
{
    private final JPanel letters;
    private final JPanel keyboard;
    private final String[] topRow = {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y", "U", "I", "O", "P"};
    private final String[] homeRow = {"A", "S", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L"};
    private final String[] bottomRow = {"Enter", "Z", "X", "C", "V", "B", "N", "M", "Backspace"};
    private final JButton[] top, home, bottom; // buttons for rows

    public WordleGUI()
    {
        this.setSize(350,400);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        letters = new JPanel();
        letters.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 5));

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            letters.add(new JTextField());

        keyboard = new JPanel();
        keyboard.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

        // top row
        top = new JButton[topRow.length];
        JPanel topkeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, topRow.length));
        for(int i = 0; i < topRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton topsize = new JButton(topRow[i]);
            topsize.setSize(50, 50);
            top[i] = topsize;
            keyboard.add(top[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(topkeys);

        // home row
        home = new JButton[homeRow.length];
        JPanel homekeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, homeRow.length));
        for(int i = 0; i < homeRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton homesize = new JButton(homeRow[i]);
            homesize.setSize(50, 50);
            home[i] = homesize;
            keyboard.add(home[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(homekeys);

        bottom = new JButton[bottomRow.length];
        JPanel bottomkeys = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, bottomRow.length));
        for(int i = 0; i < bottomRow.length; i++)
        {
            JButton bottomsize = new JButton(bottomRow[i]);
            bottomsize.setSize(50, 50);
            bottom[i] = bottomsize;
            keyboard.add(bottom[i]);
        }
        keyboard.add(bottomkeys); // weird formatting occuring here

        this.getContentPane().add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.getContentPane().add(keyboard, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new GameGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463596/418556) for an excellent keyboard layot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating three panels *topkeys*, *homekeys* and *buttomkeys* but you are not actually using them as you intended to. Add the buttons onto these and not onto the *keyboard* panel.