# Java Swing GridBagLayout not as expected

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

Some how I can't get gridwidth to work in GridBagLayout in my simple SwingApp.

I have this code in Java Swing:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

class GridBagLayt extends JFrame {
 
    GridBagLayt()
    {
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton jb4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton jb5 = new JButton("5");
        
        GridBagLayout lay = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
        
        setLayout(lay);
        cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        cons.gridheight = 1;
        cons.weightx = 1;
        cons.weighty = 1;


        cons.gridx = 0; cons.gridy = 0; 
        cons.gridwidth = 2;
        lay.setConstraints(jb1, cons);
        add(jb1);
        
        cons.gridx = 2; 
        lay.setConstraints(jb2, cons);
        add(jb2);
         
        cons.gridx = 0; cons.gridy = 1; 
        cons.gridwidth = 1;
        lay.setConstraints(jb3, cons);
        add(jb3);
        
        cons.gridx = 1;
        cons.gridwidth = 2;
        lay.setConstraints(jb4, cons);
        add(jb4);
        
        cons.gridx = 3;
        cons.gridwidth = 1;
        lay.setConstraints(jb5, cons);
        add(jb5);
        
        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(700,200);
        setVisible(true);
    }
  }

    public class SwingApp {
 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
     
            new GridBagLayt();
        }
    }
```

This is what I want to get:
[image]

But instead I get this:

[image]

I really don't know what the problem is, the coordinate and gridwidth seems ok to me, and I expected this to work, but it's not. And if I add four more buttons between this two rows, then the third row seems OK, but I don't want that:

Example: If I add this code

```
cons.gridx = 0; cons.gridy = 0; 
        cons.gridwidth = 2;
        lay.setConstraints(jb1, cons);
        add(jb1);
        
        cons.gridx = 2; 
        lay.setConstraints(jb2, cons);
        add(jb2);
        
        
        cons.gridx = 0; cons.gridy = 1; 
        cons.gridwidth = 1;
        lay.setConstraints(jb3, cons);
        add(jb3);
        
        cons.gridx = 1;
        lay.setConstraints(jb4, cons);
        add(jb4);
        
        cons.gridx = 2;
        lay.setConstraints(jb5, cons);
        add(jb5);
      
        cons.gridx = 3;
        lay.setConstraints(jb6, cons);
        add(jb6);
        
        cons.gridx = 0; cons.gridy = 2; 
        lay.setConstraints(jb7, cons);
        add(jb7);
        
        
        cons.gridx = 1; cons.gridy = 2; 
        cons.gridwidth = 2;
        lay.setConstraints(jb8, cons);
        add(jb8);
        
        cons.gridx = 3; cons.gridy = 2; 
        cons.gridwidth = 1;
        lay.setConstraints(jb9, cons);
        add(jb9);
```

Then I got this:

[image]

**But I don't want this second row**

Comment: Why do you add cells that you don't want?

Comment: just to show that it works if they are there (I found this somewhere on internet, and wanted to use it without second row, and its not working)

Comment: I would start by adding 1 & 2 to seperate container

Comment: GridBagLayouts are never as expected ;) You should really look at another layout manager, such as MigLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any suitable complex UI/layout should be split into multiple components.  This is commonly known as "compound layouts".

This allows you to better focus on the individual needs of each "area" of the layout independently.

Sometimes, you just need to fake it.

[image]

*Please note, I've used labels instead of button as a demonstration only, as MacOs buttons have a lot of space around them and this better illustrates the use of the `GridBagConstraints#insets`*

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 0, 4, 0);
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(makeFirstRow(), gbc);
            add(makeSecondRow(), gbc);
            add(makeThirdRow(), gbc);
        }

        protected JLabel makeLabel(String text) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
            label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(Color.RED);
            label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(8, 32, 8, 32));
            return label;
        }

        protected JPanel makeFirstRow() {
            JPanel rowPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

            rowPane.add(makeLabel("1"), gbc);
            rowPane.add(makeLabel("2"), gbc);

            return rowPane;
        }

        protected JPanel makeSecondRow() {
            JPanel rowPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

            rowPane.add(makeLabel("3"), gbc);
            rowPane.add(makeLabel("4"), gbc);
            rowPane.add(makeLabel("5"), gbc);

            return rowPane;
        }

        protected JPanel makeThirdRow() {
            JPanel rowPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

            rowPane.add(makeLabel("6"), gbc);
            rowPane.add(makeLabel("7"), gbc);
            rowPane.add(makeLabel("8"), gbc);

            return rowPane;
        }
    }

}
```

Now, I don't know about you, but I was tempted to create some kind of factory method which would create each row, based on the number of elements I needed in each row ... but that's me

> but with a little bit different layout. button 4 (and 7 in your layout) should be same size as buttons 1 and 2, but in your case they are 2/3 of the size of 1 and 2, and buttons 3 and 5 should be 1/2 of 1 and 2, and here they are 2/3

Then change the columns `weightx` property accordingly, for example...

[image]

```
protected JPanel makeSecondRow() {
    JPanel rowPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.fill = gbc.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 4, 0, 4);

    gbc.weightx = 0.25;
    rowPane.add(makeLabel("3"), gbc);
    gbc.weightx = 0.5;
    // This is simply adding an addition padding to the
    // labels preferred size, otherwise all three buttons
    // can be layed out at there preferred size with the
    // avaliable space
    gbc.ipadx = 64;
    rowPane.add(makeLabel("4"), gbc);
    gbc.weightx = 0.25;
    gbc.ipadx = 0;
    rowPane.add(makeLabel("5"), gbc);

    return rowPane;
}
```

Now, remember, the components own preferred size plays into this.  Without the additional `ipadx`, all three elements can be layed out their preferred size with in the available container area.

And, no, you don't "need" to specify the `weightx` for each column, this is just a demonstration, but sometimes, you might find it more useful to be absolute in your desires.

Comment: this looks nice, but with a little bit different layout. button 4 (and 7 in your layout) should be same size as buttons 1 and 2, but in your case they are 2/3 of the size of 1 and 2, and buttons 3 and 5 should be 1/2 of 1 and 2, and here they are 2/3. Anyway, the information that it's better to use multiple components is helpful, thank you

Comment: @Ewe Then change the `weightx` properties appropriately - but beware, that the preferred size of each component will have an effect on the layout, as all three elements in the row have the same preferred size, they can be layed out at the same size

Comment: Now, this is great. One more question: When setting weightx on the cells in one component should I make them always to sum up to 1? (ex. as in your case 0.25, 0.5, 0.25)

Comment: @Ewe no, you don't have to.  In my original example, I made them all equal to one, so the remaining available space was divided between them equally.  You may find you only need to specify the middle button, but there are times when you want to make your desires very clear

Answer (score 1):

I finally got this GUI to work, but I had to use two hacks that I don't recommend using.

[image: Example]

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

The reason this GUI is difficult to achieve is that the `GridBagLayout` has nothing to use to size the four columns.  So, borrowing from the OP, I created a row of empty `JLabels` before creating the rows of `JButtons`.  I sized the `JLabels` based on the size of a `JButton`.

I wasn't sure until I tried it, but a `gridheight` of zero keeps the `JLabels` in the same physical location as the first row of `JButtons`.

Here's the complete, ugly, runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutTest2 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutTest2());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createPanels(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanels() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        gbc.weightx = 0.0;
        
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        Dimension d = button1.getPreferredSize();
        
        gbc.gridheight = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setPreferredSize(d);
            panel.add(label, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
        }

        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        gbc.weightx = 1.0;
        panel.add(button1, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        panel.add(button2, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        panel.add(button3, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx += 1;
        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        panel.add(button4, gbc);
        
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
        panel.add(button5, gbc);

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to add panels/labels with height 0 in the second row, and that was not working (it still had a space between second and third row), but this works, also I tried to add 4 labels and the first two buttons on y=0 and it is also ok. But now I'm curious, why this is not recommended?

Comment: *My mistake, it also works with adding labels with height 0 in the second row

Comment: @Ewe: These types of hacks lead to hard to maintain, hard to modify correctly code that breaks in mysterious ways.  In this simple example, you can understand what's going on.  In a 100 `JPanel` GUI, it's not so obvious.

Comment: *The reason this GUI is difficult to achieve is that the GridBagLayout has nothing to use to size the four columns* - I posted an answer showing how to use properties of the GridBagLayout without creating extra components.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one additional `JPanel` for each line, and would not extend `JFrame` (unless needed, that is, adding functionality to it)):

```
public class SwingApp2 {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingApp2::new);
    }

    private SwingApp2()
    {
        var jb1 = new JButton("1");
        var jb2 = new JButton("2");
        var jb3 = new JButton("3");
        var jb4 = new JButton("4");
        var jb5 = new JButton("5");

        var line1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        var gbc = new GridBagConstraints(RELATIVE, 0, 1, 1, 1.0, 1.0, CENTER, BOTH, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0);
        line1.add(jb1, gbc);
        line1.add(jb2, gbc);

        var line2 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        line2.add(jb3, gbc);
        gbc.weightx *= 2;
        line2.add(jb4, gbc);
        gbc.weightx /= 2;
        line2.add(jb5, gbc);

        var frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // using GridLayout so the lines are same height
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        frame.add(line1);
        frame.add(line2);
        frame.setSize(700,200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

<sub>Just one way to do it, very dependent of how the components should be resized if the GUI size is changed</sub>
<sub>Also be aware that sizes will change according to preferred size, that is, labels content</sub>

Answer (score 1):

> The reason this GUI is difficult to achieve is that the GridBagLayout has nothing to use to size the four columns

`GridBagLayout` does have properties that allow you to define default values for columns that don't have components as is demonstrated below:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridBagLayoutTest3 implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new GridBagLayoutTest3());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(createPanels(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createPanels() {

        //  Create the GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints to be used by the panel

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(gbl);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);

        //  Create and add components to the panel

        JButton button1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        panel.add(button1, gbc);

        gbc.gridx += 2;
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        panel.add(button2, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy++;
        JButton button3 = new JButton("Button 3");
        panel.add(button3, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 2;
        gbc.gridx += 1;
        JButton button4 = new JButton("Button 4");
        panel.add(button4, gbc);

        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        gbc.gridx += 2;
        JButton button5 = new JButton("Button 5");
        panel.add(button5, gbc);

        //  Set properties of the GridBagLayout for columns without components in a single column

        int[] columns = new int[4];
        Arrays.fill(columns, button1.getPreferredSize().width);
        gbl.columnWidths = columns;
        double[] weights = new double[4];
        Arrays.fill(weights, 1.0);
        gbl.columnWeights = weights;

        return panel;
    }

}
```

Note: you can also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463596/131872 which has a more involved example showing how to use this approach for a "keyboard" layout of buttons.

Answer (score 0):

GridBagLayout is concerned with alignment, not proportions.  Occasionally it can be used to lay out components with equal sizes, but it’s not good at that.

[SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SpringLayout.html), however, is quite good at that, and has methods specifically for doing that.  The trade-off is that SpringLayout is hard to use and easy to use incorrectly.  It works like the “form layouts” of the 1990s.  For each component in the layout, you have to state where at least one horizontal edge and one vertical edge should be located, relative to the edges of the container or relative to the edges of other child components.

First, it’s better to create your container, rather than extending JFrame.  It doesn’t make sense to subclass JFrame, since you’re merely using JFrame, not changing its behavior:

```
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
```

Next, let’s compute a consistent size for the small buttons:

```
JButton[] buttons = { jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4, jb5 };

Spring width = Spring.constant(0);
Spring height = Spring.constant(0);
for (JButton button : buttons) {
    width = Spring.max(width, Spring.width(button));
    height = Spring.max(height, Spring.height(button));
}
```

Next, let’s make buttons 1, 2, and 4 twice as wide:

```
Spring largeButtonWidth = Spring.scale(width, 2);
```

Now we can use those Springs to create [constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/SpringLayout.Constraints.html) for each button:

```
Spring zero = Spring.constant(0);

panel.add(jb1, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
    zero, zero, largeButtonWidth, height));

panel.add(jb2, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
    largeButtonWidth, zero, largeButtonWidth, height));

panel.add(jb3, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
    zero, height, width, height));

panel.add(jb4, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
    width, height, largeButtonWidth, height));

panel.add(jb5, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
    Spring.sum(width, largeButtonWidth), height, width, height));
```

Finally, we need to tell the layout how big the container itself should be.  It needs to be wide enough to accommodate jb2 and jb5, and tall enough to accommodate jb3, jb4, and jb5.  We could use any of those to specify the container’s preferred size, but jb5 is probably the easiest choice:

```
layout.putConstraint(
    SpringLayout.EAST, panel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, jb5);
layout.putConstraint(
    SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, jb5);
```

Putting it all together looks like this:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Spring;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class RelativeButtonSizesDemo {
    private final JFrame frame;

    public RelativeButtonSizesDemo() {
        JButton jb1 = new JButton("1");
        JButton jb2 = new JButton("2");
        JButton jb3 = new JButton("3");
        JButton jb4 = new JButton("4");
        JButton jb5 = new JButton("5");

        JButton[] buttons = { jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4, jb5 };

        Spring width = Spring.constant(0);
        Spring height = Spring.constant(0);
        for (JButton button : buttons) {
            width = Spring.max(width, Spring.width(button));
            height = Spring.max(height, Spring.height(button));
        }

        // jb1, jb2, and jb4 will be twice as wide as the other buttons.
        Spring largeButtonWidth = Spring.scale(width, 2);

        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);

        Spring zero = Spring.constant(0);

        panel.add(jb1, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
            zero, zero, largeButtonWidth, height));

        panel.add(jb2, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
            largeButtonWidth, zero, largeButtonWidth, height));

        panel.add(jb3, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
            zero, height, width, height));

        panel.add(jb4, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
            width, height, largeButtonWidth, height));

        panel.add(jb5, new SpringLayout.Constraints(
            Spring.sum(width, largeButtonWidth), height, width, height));

        // Set preferred size of panel itself to accommodate buttons.
        layout.putConstraint(
            SpringLayout.EAST, panel, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, jb5);
        layout.putConstraint(
            SpringLayout.SOUTH, panel, 0, SpringLayout.SOUTH, jb5);

        frame = new JFrame("Relative Button Sizes Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new RelativeButtonSizesDemo().show());
    }
}
```