# I need to make photo fill bottom row of gui with picture instead of just half of the bottom

Tags: java, swing

I tried to change image size, didn't fill bottom of screen with `src/pipe_pan23.jpeg` photo.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GridBagLayoutExample extends JFrame {
    public GridBagLayoutExample() {
        setTitle("GridBag Layout Example");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int imageSize = Math.min(screenSize.width / 3, screenSize.height / 3);

        // Add buttons with resized images to specific cells
        addButton("src/Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg", 0, 0, gbc, imageSize, imageSize, 1, 2);
        addButton("src/pipe_pan23.jpeg", 1, 2, gbc, imageSize, imageSize, 3, 1);
        addButton("src/tori.jpeg", 1, 1, gbc, imageSize, imageSize, 1, 1);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addButton(String imagePath, int gridx, int gridy, GridBagConstraints gbc, int width, int height, int gridwidth, int gridheight) {
        try {
            Image resizedImage = resizeImage(imagePath, width, height);
            ImageIcon resizedIcon = new ImageIcon(resizedImage);

            JButton button = new JButton(resizedIcon);
            gbc.gridx = gridx;
            gbc.gridy = gridy;
            gbc.gridwidth = gridwidth;
            gbc.gridheight = gridheight;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;

            add(button, gbc);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Image resizeImage(String imagePath, int width, int height) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(new File(imagePath));
        Image resizedImage = originalImage.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        return new ImageIcon(resizedImage).getImage();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(GridBagLayoutExample::new);
    }
}
```

I want to fill the bottom of the GUI with `src/pipe_pan23.jpeg` so that it completely fills the two squares in the bottom row. Create a 9 x 9 grid using `GridBagLayout`.
Add 3 different icon images to a group of cells
The images are stored in the same directory/folder as your Java project in your IDE.
Remember, the `GridBagLayout` allows for grouping of cells.

Comment: [Edit] your question and post a screen capture of how your GUI looks now, as well as another screen capture showing how you want your GUI to look. Maybe you should also post links to the images `Cat_November_2010-1a.jpg`, `pipe_pan23.jpeg` and `tori.jpeg`.

Comment: *Create a 9 x 9 grid using GridBagLayout.* - you can't just create a  9x9 grid unless you have 9 components. That is you can't just randomly say a component has a width of 3.  unless you have a row with components in each column with a valid width. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463596/131872 for more information and a possible solution.